# Reduce and operation equation

Tags: logic, arithmetic, binary-operations

I want to reduce this equation into (A & B) form

Equation:  (X & Z) * (Y & Z)

Here

& is bitwise AND operation (http://www.xcprod.com/titan/XCSB-DOC/binary_and.html)

$*$ is multiplication

X, Y, Z are integers

I thought that it would be (X*Y & Z)

But I think I am wrong.

Can anybody please help me in this.

I am not getting it.

Comment: What is the definition of $&,*$ and what are $A,B,X,Y$?

Comment: @Phicar Edited the question